# Union based on string of identifiers PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, qgis-3, parcel

I have a table of documents relating to several parcels of land. I have in this table the identifiers (numerals, sometimes interspaced by "/"- text field, delimited by commas). I also have a land division table that contains these same identifiers and geometries.

What I want is to assign geometry to the entries in this table, based on these identifiers. Where there is just one, no problem exists, because a simple "=" will do the trick.
Where the problem is at, is in cases where there is more than one parcel I want to join them in one polygon.

What I have so far only produces an empty row:

```sql
SELECT o.*, st_union(a.geometry) as geometry
FROM   "documents" o, parcels a 
WHERE  o.identifier like '%' || a.identifier || '%'
```

EDIT:

To clarify, my table that I wish to add geometry to (it has none to begin with) has a structure like this:

> identifier | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 ...
>
> 201,202,203/1,203/2 | x | x2 | x3 | x4 ...
>
> 206 | x | x2 | x3 | x4 ...

While the parcel table is always like:

> identifier | f1 | f2 | f3 | geometry ...
>
> 206 | x | x2 | x3 | binaryGeometry ...

In the example above, parcels 201,202,203/1,203/2 need to be merged into one polygon.
I feel like this kind of task should be easily achievable, yet I can't make it work.

Comment: Not really a GIS questions (even if it in a PostGIS database, no geom involved) more DBA. Don't play with `like`, play more with regular expressions.

Comment: If the result is empty, then you might want to drop the unary ST_Union and consult with [dba.se] on getting the JOIN correct before moving on to adding the geometry back in.

Comment: Geometry is very much involved, I need a union of several polygons. The parcel database has one entry per parcel. My table can have several parcels written in one field.